# Browser for flash videos and RTSP streaming support

Tags: lumia, internet, browser

Are there any browser for playing flash videos and rtsp streaming support?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no support for Flash. Flash is an outdated technology that no-one should support. If you find a website using Flash, please ask them to convert it to HTML5 instead.

Regarding RTSP, no, there is not.

Answer (score -2):

Dolphin Browser, sure. It supports flash. Useful in Android, also.

Comment: I can't see that in the store, do you have a link at all?

Comment: I've seen Dolphin for Android, but can't find it for Windows Phone either.